# how many multiple image in css background

Tags: css

I just want to know how many images I can use as a CSS background
or  any other way to use multiple background images in a class so that I could use multiple of images

I am trying to use this but it is accepting only two images

```
#example1 {
    background: url(img_flwr.gif) right bottom no-repeat, url(paper.gif) left top repeat;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please set up a working example and share it with us.

Comment: Can't find any reference to an upper limit (although it's likely to add to CSS bloat I feel) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds. Without a demo it's hard to say why it's not working for you,

Comment: next time: google ! this is so basic, you didn't even  look for an answer, you just ask here because you are lazy..

google > background (shorthand for..., background-image)
google > background-image (A FULL EXPLAINTION OF WHAT YOU NEED)

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple images in background

```
body {
background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif),url(a.gif),url(b.gif);

}
```